# Setting NSPredicate returns only 1 object in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm new to core data and currently working on the beginning stage of my project which incorporates YouTube API. I want to show lists of videos according to a user selected category. The API request works fine (I set it up so the call returns 20 videos each time, for each page). When I delete the line "fr.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category == %@", self.category)" from my fetchedResultsController constructor, UITableView would show videos, from the previous category I clicked on, along with videos in the current category, and therefore the rows in section increments by 20 (20, 40, 60 ...). Problem is when I added that NSPredicate line back in, everything else seems to work fine, except UITableView would only show 1 video even though the API call still returns 20 videos each time.

Here's how I set up fetchedResultsController

```
    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
         let fr = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Video")
         fr.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]
         fr.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category == %@", self.category)
         let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fr, managedObjectContext: self.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
          fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
          return fetchedResultsController
    }()
```

Here's the code for the UITableViewController: https://github.com/leqilong/TubeCat/blob/master/TubeCat/VideosTableViewController.swift

Comment: The obvious question is, are you sure that `self.category` matches more than one out of those 20?

Comment: @TomHarrington Yeah, since each batch of the 20 videos is returned from the API call which searches based on one specific category (self.category).

Comment: Can you show details of the `Category` class - is it a subclass of NSManagedObject?

Comment: @pbasdf Yeah it is. Here's my Category class: [Category](https://github.com/leqilong/TubeCat/blob/master/TubeCat/Category.swift), [Category properties](https://github.com/leqilong/TubeCat/blob/master/TubeCat/Category%2BCoreDataProperties.swift)

Comment: OK. It looks like you have set the relationship from Category to Video as to-one.  That means every time you assign a video to a category, the previous video is removed.  Hence only the last video has the correct Category (the others will all have category = nil).  Change the relationship to be to-many.  The properties should then show `videos` as an Set (or NSSet).

Comment: @pbasdf That's it. Thanks!